# Firebase Dynamic Link New Install Events

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to get the event of New install or App open/re-open events in my Android App whenever user click on any dynamic link.

Following events are captured in Analytics as per documentation:

```
dynamic_link_first_open

dynamic_link_app_open
```

But I can't find any way to get these from sample listener.

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution to my above question. Sharing details here.

Below code is tested from PlayStore also.

You can get mentioned two events through `pendingDynamicLinkData` callback object received from `addOnSuccessListener`.

Complete code to get link and associated Dynamic link data here.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, pendingDynamicLinkData -> {
                    // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                    try {
                        Uri deepLink = null;
                        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                            deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();

                            sendInstallDetailToAPI(pendingDynamicLinkData.getExtensions());

                        }
                        CgUtils.showLog(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onSuccess" + deepLink);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        CgUtils.showLog(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure" + e);
                    }

                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, e -> CgUtils.showLog(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure" + e));
```

Below method to send the Dynamic Link data to your backend API if you want.

```
private void sendInstallDetailToAPI(Bundle deepBundle) {

      
        Bundle deepLinkData = deepBundle.getBundle("scionData");
        if (deepLinkData != null) {
            Bundle appReOpenBundle = deepLinkData.getBundle("dynamic_link_app_open");
            boolean isInstall = false;
            String medium = "", source = "", campaign = "", shortLink = "";
            if (appReOpenBundle != null) {
                medium = appReOpenBundle.getString("medium", "NA");
                source = appReOpenBundle.getString("source", "NA");
                campaign = appReOpenBundle.getString("campaign", "NA");
                shortLink = appReOpenBundle.getString("dynamic_link_link_id", "NA");
            }

            Bundle appFirstOpenBundle = deepLinkData.getBundle("dynamic_link_first_open");

            if (appFirstOpenBundle != null) {
                isInstall = true;
                medium = appFirstOpenBundle.getString("medium", "NA");
                source = appFirstOpenBundle.getString("source", "NA");
                campaign = appFirstOpenBundle.getString("campaign", "NA");
                shortLink = appFirstOpenBundle.getString("dynamic_link_link_id", "NA");
            }

        // Send ABOVE detail to your respective APIs


        }
    }
```

Now If `isInstall` flag is true that means it's first time open after install else reopen.

Comment: hi @Anukool, I am using Kotlin, I've tried your code with adjustment related to kotlin, but I got empty when getting the pendingDynamicLInkData.extension. what do you think I am missing? other than that the dynamic link is working normal

Comment: I am getting campaign, medium, source blank, can you share any sample url for passing these params.